# Angular material layout-align = "center center" not working

Tags: html, css, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I'm trying to use the layout-align = "center center" which should align the content at center both vertically and horizontally. But it's only aligning the content horizontally and not vertically.

Here's the plnkr [link](http://embed.plnkr.co/GKot1i15DAi6OFP7G0BD/preview) of the code I'm trying.

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
<md-toolbar>
<div class="md-toolbar-tools">
  <h2 flex>Hello Angular-material!</h2>
</div>
</md-toolbar>
<div class="flexbox-parent">
  <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
   <div flex="15">First line</div>
   <div flex="15">Second line</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: it may be because it use flexbox... maybe is a compatibility issue with your browser ? you can take a look at http://caniuse.com/

Comment: I don't get it, you want something like [this](http://imgur.com/aQ9DNu5)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The reason why it is not centering it vertically is because your div containing the layout-align attribute does not have a height.

Try something like

```
<div class="flexbox-parent">
  <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" style="min-height: 500px">
   <div flex="15">First line</div>
   <div flex="15">Second line</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can centering be done on the whole viewport of the browser?

Comment: @Prabhdeep : My div with layout-align has got a min-height in px. Still it is not working for me.

Comment: If you run the code above in jsfiddle it works just fine, try making sure you have no other classes or styling that is overriding your elements.

Comment: Isn't this exactly the same as what's in question? How is the answer just copy pasting html from the question?

Comment: @BuffetTime You're totally right.. strange. it seemed that my answer got modified a couple months back by me.. I must have been out of my mind or something. o.O

Comment: Alright cool, ya I saw this while checking through and thought i should say smoething :P

Comment: sorry I am not shooting the messenger...why the f would it need a height? it's supposed to be centered, so center it! lol

Answer (score 3):

Flexbox vertical centering works well with defining height for the parent element:

```
<div class="flexbox-parent">
  <div layout="row" layout-align="center center"  style="height: 100vh">
   <div flex="15">First line</div>
   <div flex="15">Second line</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center" style="height: 100vh; width: 100vh"
```

on your parent div

Comment: The question was related to Angular.js/ angular-material 1.x.
Angular 2+ syntax you've used might confuse some folks.

Comment: this works well for me ```.center-dialog-vertically{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}```